# Is there a way to add a hidden folder (with . prefix) to SourceTree?

Tags: macos, git, unix, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm using [Spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) on OS X. I want to add the folder `.emacs.d` to SourceTree since it's clone of a git repo. However I can't even locate any hidden folder from SourceTree -> File -> Open. Does that mean I'll have to rely on some other git interface?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Found out that you can just drag the folder into "Repository Browser"

Answer (score 1):

Hidden folders are by default not shown in Finder. To view hidden folders and files in the Finder window that SourceTree opens use the MacOS keyboard shortcut `⌘ + Shift + .`.